# Hiding certain choices in a qualtrics matrix

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I am very new to programming but have come across a situation in my work where I believe I need to use some javascript to make my survey manageable for the participant. The client wants to use Qualtrics as a scheduling system. Faculty identify time slots that they are available and the survey would start by hiding the ones that they will not be available for. Then dynamically hides buttons as the quotas fill for a given time slot.

My matrix table is 10 columns x 15 rows to accommodate all the times and days. I'm trying to reuse snips of codes that I have found online and so far have gotten to:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{

    $("QR~QID14~1~4").up().hide();
});
```

This is hiding a choice, but instead of row 1 column 4 it is hiding row 1 column 15 (whose inspect element is QR~QID14~1~10). Whatever I change my column number to (4 in the example) it is always hiding the check box in the last column. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. So I've gone into my results and realize it is hiding the correct button but the rest of the buttons are shifting left so it appears that the last button is hidden.

Once I get it to hide the correct column I want to add conditions to my code that will hide it based on the value of a quota, which I believe would look like:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{

    if ('${qo://QUOTAID/QuotaCount}' > 0) $("QR~QID14~1~4").up().hide();
});
```

Where I would find the QUOTAID via Qualtric's piped text option

I know I can format this as a list but there are too many options for some faculty to make that look right.

Comment: The HTML or XML structure of the document might be helpful.

Comment: $ in Qualtrics refers to prototypejs, not jquery (you might want to change/remove the jquery tag)

Answer (score 1):

You want to hide the contents of the table cell, not the cell itself.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    $('QR~QID14~1~4').up('td').childElements().invoke('hide');
});
```